# What is "Structured" in Structured Query Language?

Tags: sql, terminology

What does the "Structured" word means in SQL?

Is it because this(SQL) language statements are organized into Clauses, expressions and predicates?

Because of this organization, is it called "Structured" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The original full name was SEQUEL, [which stood fo](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122134941/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/cs/people/chamberlin/sequel-1974.pdf)r "Structured English Query Language". It later had to be renamed to SQL due to trademark issues.

So basically, it was yet another attempt to sell a programming language as "just like English, except with a formal syntax" (hence "structured").

Comment: Interesting "However,  there is also a large class of users who, while they are not computer specialists, would be willing to learn to interact with a computer in a reasonably high-level, non-procedural querylanguage.  Examples of such users are accountants, engineers,  architects,  and urban planners. It is for this class of users that SEQUEL is intended."

Comment: It is highly questionable whether this has had the intended effect! The non-compsci-written queries I've met have generally tended towards the barely-manageable kind of procedural-mindset mess where a series of heavy correlated subqueries are used instead of basic joins.

Comment: @Andomar, @bobince: Enabling non-programmers to program via a "intuitive" or "natural" language or interface is a pipe dream that gets re-invented every couple of years.

Comment: So true. Microsoft English Query was launched with fanfare with SQL Server 2000 but dropped in SQL 2005.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, SQL is actually an abbreviation of SEQUEL, or Structured English Query Language.  It was meant to have queries that everyone could read.  The structured part means that you can only use a structured English; i.e. `select col1 from table1`, but not `give col1 out of table1`.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly because it is a backronym.  They needed a S to make Sequel.

Answer (score 2):

from: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_sql_is_called_structured_query_language

SQL, the standard that was later developed from Codd's work, provides a means of describing data with its **natural structure** only - that is, without superimposing any additional structure for machine representation purposes.

Comment: Could someone clarify this answer? What's an example of the " superimposing of additional structure for machine representation purposes" that SQL lacks?