# why sql so called structured language?

Tags: sql, database

what structure means here? Is it means there is a specific structure of query in sql.

Comment: SQL means Structured Query Language. You can easy find out informations about this just browsing the internet.

Comment: You can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938908/what-is-structured-in-structured-query-language